# Can't post notification from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

This is my code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("isOnline"), object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disableMarcar), name: Notification.Name("isOnline"), object: nil)
```

If I post the notification from any ViewController it works but from the AppDelegate.swift in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {` doesn't work.

Does anyone know why? 
I've seen other post but none answers my question.

Comment: What kind of functionality are you doing in the ViewController that would have this listener?

Because, if it's triggered from AppDelegate, before that ViewController is initialized, it would obviously not hit the listener function, since it's yet to become a listener for this notification.

Comment: In the viewcontroller I check my api and I disablr/enable some elements

Comment: The view controller will anyway be initialized after the app finishes launching, so you can go ahead and just make the API calls, probably from the viewDidLoad of the controller, right?

Answer (score 0):

Posting notifications before an observer is registerered does nothing, I'd consider that a feature. Do this instead:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disableMarcar), name: Notification.Name("isOnline"), object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("isOnline"), object: nil
```

Comment: The func that the observer is going to execute is in another file, in a viewcontroller

Comment: In that case make sure the observing VC is initialized and actually calls `addObserver` before posting the notification.

Comment: Can I initialize a VC before a func in appdelegate? The notification posts in appdelegate

Comment: Genereally speaking, you can. The details depend on how your app initializes itself, e.g. whether its root VC comes from a storyboard/nib or is setup in code.